# How to fix 'Error: querySrv EREFUSED' when connecting to MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am new to MongoDB 4.0.6 and tried to implement it into my website using Node/Express.js, but when I try to connect to `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGOUSER}:${process.env.MONGOPASS}@main-03xkr.mongodb.net/main` I'm getting this error:

> { Error: querySrv EREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.main-03xkr.mongodb.net
>       at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:199:19)
>     errno: 'EREFUSED',
>     code: 'EREFUSED',
>     syscall: 'querySrv',
>     hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.main-03xkr.mongodb.net' }

I've tried connecting to `mongodb://localhost:27017/main`, but this **does** seem work.

Here is the relevant code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Database
const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGOUSER}:${process.env.MONGOPASS}@main-03xkr.mongodb.net/main`;
const localURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/main';

var Project = require('./models/project');

mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', () => console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB'));
db.on('error', (e) => console.log(e));

// Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Project.find({}, (e, projects) => {
    if (e) console.log(e);

    res.render('home.ejs', {
      projects: projects
    });
  });
});
```

So does anyone know how to fix this error and maybe explain what is happening here?

Comment: Hey Alex, have you whitelisted your IP with MongoAtlas?

Comment: Yes, I have whitelisted every IP using `0.0.0.0/0` @VtoCorleone

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you're encountering this error try to use the older connection string for Node.js 2.2.12 or later:

```
mongodb://<username>:<password>@main-shard-00-00-03xkr.mongodb.net:27017,main-shard-00-01-03xkr.mongodb.net:27017,main-shard-00-02-03xkr.mongodb.net:27017/main?ssl=true&replicaSet=Main-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true
```

According to MongoDB, SRV is possibly not working due to Mongoose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked for me as well. But I would love to know why isn't it working with 3.0?

Comment: When I asked the MongoDB staff, they said it might be because of Mongoose, but I don't know the specific answer.

Comment: I encountered this error but due to inactivity of my website. The mongodb connection automatically paused the instance when there's no activity of the website. I resume the connection and all goes well. Cheers!

Answer (score 61):

I had this same error when I was connecting with `Node` version `3.0 or later` and I resolved it by downgrading to `2.2.12 or later` version:

[image: downgrade]

Comment: This works although the "mongodb" package i am using from npm is at ^v3.5.7 which should be considered for "3.0 or later" connections. But the "3.0 or later" one works for my AWS EC2 instance just fine but not locally.

local node -v ->  13.0.x
AWS node -v -> 10.20.1

Comment: Same here, Windows runs just fine but Linux with the same configuration doesn't (mongodb@3.6.8 node@14.15.4). Using the older connection string works for some reason.

Answer (score 24):

In my case, it's mainly a DNS issue in mac, to resolve it, just add google DNS server under the DNS section in mac book pro settings:

```
8.8.8.8
4.4.4.4
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @HMagdy I was just looking for this.

Comment: This worked for me. Macbook and it is shared coworking space wifi. No issue with my personal wifi though.

Comment: This work for me after resume my cluster.

Comment: It worked for me too. I was on my home wifi. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15):

This error occurs sometimes when you are using MongoDB Atlas and lost your internet connectivity. You will not be able to access your database.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure to change the node version to 2.2.12:

[image]

And add IP address:

[image]

Comment: This was my problem - the new unified connection string would sometimes work, sometimes not. It was extremely frustrating to troubleshoot. Went back to the old connection string format and it instantly worked again.

Answer (score 5):

Pass option `{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }` to the MongoClient constructor

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGOUSER}:${process.env.MONGOPASS}@main-03xkr.mongodb.net/main"

mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was throwing this error due mongodb cluster auto paused because of prolonged inactivity. I just resumed it, then it started properly.

Answer (score 4):

You have `undefined` in your connection string.  I don't know if this is typo or not.  But try changing

```
const uri = `mongodb+srv://undefined:${process.env.MONGOPASS}@main-03xkr.mongodb.net/main`;
```

to

```
const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGOUSER}:${process.env.MONGOPASS}@main-03xkr.mongodb.net/main`;
```

I use MongoAtlas for a project and that string (minus the undefined user) looks correct.

Comment: haha... interesting. I'd scrub that from your stack post just so people can't try and guess a password for your credentials.  Can you try connecting to the instance through the CLI? https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/mongo-shell-connection/ Just to test that your credentials and URL is correct?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It does connect using the CLI, so I guess it must be something in my code.

Answer (score 3):

In our case antivirus/firewall is blocking,

Try to disable antivirus/firewall and check again. hope it will work.

Comment: My god. I had to disable Win10 firewall for atlas connection to work...

Answer (score 3):

```
Error: querySrv ESERVFAIL _mongodb._tcp.databasename-zcbag.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:202:19) {
  errno: 'ESERVFAIL',
  code: 'ESERVFAIL',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.databasename-zcbag.mongodb.net'
}
```

---

If the above code is your output then there is no error in your code. You have to check your network connection. Maybe you have to switch your network from the phone network to another or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

```
MongoClient.connect(
  "mongodb://USER:PASSWORT@mflix-shard-00-00-r5yfb.mongodb.net/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=mflix-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority",
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
)
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err.stack)
    process.exit(1)
  })
  .then(async client => {
    await MoviesDAO.injectDB(client)
    await UsersDAO.injectDB(client)
    await CommentsDAO.injectDB(client)
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
    })
  })
```

Maybe can works with MongoClient( not Mongoose )

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error was happening when the **DNS configuration** in my TP-Link Router was missing.

I've installed OpenWRT firmware on it and forgot to adjust DNS settings.

I was able to open YouTube or any other website because that's not my main router, but could not connect to database.

It was an internet issue, like **@Kamesh Kumar Singh** said in his answer.

I think that this is not an usual answer for this question, but may help someone.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if you are not able to connect to mongoDB Atlas database. Your server runs successfully but you get this error while connecting to database. Make sure your internet connection is good and try again you won't see this error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue occurred because MongoDB paused my cluster due to over 4 months of inactivity. After I logged in to my account and resumed the activity of the cluster, the issue was immediately resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I solved mine by going into the MongoDB -> login -> databases -> connect -> connect your application (middle one) -> copy the code -> paste the code into the mongooseDB code in my .JS file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv/config');

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.THE_MONGO_DB_URL_GOES_HERE_IN_DOTENV_FILE, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Database connected!"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

  const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
  }, {strict: false});

  const DataEntry = mongoose.model('n26-users-collection', PostSchema); 

  module.exports = DataEntry;
```

Answer (score 0):

### **"Not in the root folder" scenario:**

> Create a .env file in the **root directory** of your project. https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv

[image]

One scenario for this error is to create [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) `.env` file --**NOT**-- in the `root folder` (Under `/src` for example).

Than this code:

```
const url = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${
  process.env.DB_USER_PASSWORD
}@${process.env.DB_CLUSTER}.mongodb.net`;

console.log(url)
```

output:

```
mongodb+srv://undefined:undefined@undefined.mongodb.net
```

So the `"undefined"` URL connection:

```
const client = new MongoClient(url);
```

Throw 3 warnings:

> (node:27240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: **Error: querySrv
> ENOTFOUND** _mongodb._tcp.undefined.mongodb.net
> at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:207:19)

> (node:27240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by  rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled
> promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`
> (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1)

> (node:27240) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.

---

**One more "close" scenario:**
`.env` in the root folder but the file is **empty**:

[image]

---

#### Solution

The **first step** to solve this issue is to `console.log(url)` and check if `process.env` returns the correct [Connection String](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/).

---

Related:

- **dotenv github readme**: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#readme
- **Connect to a MongoDB Database Using Node.js
  :** https://developer.mongodb.com/quickstart/node-connect-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

For the most part this error occurs when there is a mongodb driver and comnnection string mismatch. Ensure that use the conncetion string and its equivalent driver as specified in the Mongodb atlas connect section. Important Tip, dont use the latest mongodb driver. Use the previous version. You can acert conncetion issues easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 10/11, go to the connected networks property setting and assign `Google`'s dns: `8.8.8.8`. Worked for my case.

[image]