# MongoDB Mongoose error when connecting to the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have encountered a problem when connecting to a MongoDB database using Mongoose. I am using node js and express.

here is the error:

```
Error: queryTxt ESERVFAIL businessregistration-npeym.mongodb.net


(node:66755) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: queryTxt ESERVFAIL businessregistration-npeym.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:206:19)
(node:66755) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error 
originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting 
a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled 
promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see 
https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

I think the main error is this: 
`Error: queryTxt ESERVFAIL businessregistration-npeym.mongodb.net`

My code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const Schema = require("./Schema");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@businessregistration-npeym.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
);

mongoose.connection.on("connected", function () {
  console.info("Connected!\n\n");
});
mongoose.connection.on("error", function (err) {
  console.error(`ERROR!!! The error is: ${err}\n\n`); // error is consoled here
});
mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", function () {
  console.warn(
    "The connection has been lost. This is because it got disconnected.\n\n"
  );
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

I do not know why this is suddenly happening. If you could help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, scrolling through stack overflow, I finally found a solution.

Credits to JOSEPH KASULE from stack overflow: [Thanks!](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10143979/joseph-kasule)

Link to answer: [How to fix 'Error: querySrv EREFUSED' when connecting to MongoDB Atlas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499175/how-to-fix-error-querysrv-erefused-when-connecting-to-mongodb-atlas)

Scroll down to the correct answer to find it.

Turns out, I have to use an older connection method for connecting. I had to select a node version of 2.2.12 or greater:

[image: 2.2.12 or greater]

and I have to use an older version of connecting:

Instead of this:

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@businessregistration-npeym.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I had to use this:

```
mongodb://<username>:<password>@businessregistration-shard-00-00-npeym.mongodb.net:27017,businessregistration-shard-00-01-npeym.mongodb.net:27017,businessregistration-shard-00-02-npeym.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=BusinessRegistration-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

when connecting to Mongo DB using mongoose.

The reason is that according to Mongo DB, SRV was not working properly due to Mongoose.