# How to use 'Node.js 3.0 or later' on mongoose connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing a Node JS API but suddently, my MongoDB connection configuration stopped working.

This is how my configuration looks like:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

try {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@hackerrank.jyajn.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false});
  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
}
catch(error) {
  console.log(error);
}

module.exports = mongoose;
```

This connection was working until yesterday, but when I tried to run it today it threw the error:

```
Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND
```

I saw on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499175/how-to-fix-error-querysrv-erefused-when-connecting-to-mongodb-atlas) that

> According to MongoDB, SRV is possibly not working due to Mongoose.

So I changed the connection string to the "Node.js 2.2.12 or later" version, as mentioned on the post and it really worked.

My question is, why did this happen? Shouldn't I be able to use the latest connection string, since my node version is ***v12.17.0***?