# Error while connecting NodeJS with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, api, connection

I was saving and retrieving data in MongoDB using NodeJS. It was working properly. Now suddenly, it has started to display the following error message in the console. If I restart the NodeJS server then, again sometimes it works. How to fix this. Is this error related to MongoDB or mongoose itself?
I am using mongoose `"mongoose": "^5.12.11",` and MongoDB driver version `NodeJS 3.6 or later` in MongoDB Atlas.

```
Error: querySrv ECONNREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.socail.xngew.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.socail.xngew.mongodb.net'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading the node version will be the solution for your issue. You can find more details from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499175/how-to-fix-error-querysrv-erefused-when-connecting-to-mongodb-atlas)