# nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: mongodb, nodemon

I cannot connect to Mongo using mongoose ,,,

querySrv ENODATA _mongodb._tcp.todocluster-3kozc.mongodb.net
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in another post [Error: querySrv ENODATA _mongodb._tcp.blog-cluster-0hb5z.mongodb.net at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54484673/error-querysrv-enodata-mongodb-tcp-blog-cluster-0hb5z-mongodb-net-at-queryreq)

For some reason the dns server did not return srv records, changing the dns server to one that returns those records fixed the problem. (I used https://use.opendns.com/ to fix the it)

it works now ...

Answer (score 0):

```
npx kill-port 5000
```

then,

```
yarn start or npm start
```